# Tomee MultipartProvider didn't consider body as readable

Tags: java, jax-rs, cxf, apache-tomee, java-17

During my java migration (8 to 17), I experienced some problems with Tomee plus 8.0.15 (inderectly Apache CXF, cxf shade 3.5.5).

In my application, I use **multipart/form-data** in some requests, because some forms send classic values (like String, Long) and a file. The main problem is that Tomee don't use the class [MultipartProvider](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/3.5.x-fixes/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/provider/MultipartProvider.java) which is in charge to split the **form-data** body and provide the correct values in parameters. Instead of that, it fill the first variable with the all content of the request.

Example of my resource, using the [recommended way by Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-multiparts.html).

```java
// imports ...

@Path("/test")
@Stateless
public class MyResource {
  // ...

  @POST
  @Path("/{id}")
  @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
  public Response edit(
    @PathParam("id") Long id, 
    @Multipart("name") String name,
    @Multipart("file") Attachment image
  ) {

    // DOING some stuff with name

    return Response.ok().build();
  }

  // ...
}
```

After some hours of debugging, I found the reason. The method [MultipartProvider#isSupported](https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/081c9b002f338036b3c2d272632fcda3b4b7ce79/rt/frontend/jaxrs/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/provider/MultipartProvider.java#L125C23-L125C23) is clearly called but the result is false. It is essentially due to `AnnotationUtils.getAnnotation(anns, Multipart.class)` that returns false.

When I inpect `Annotation[] anns` variable, it is not really a table of Annotation but rather Java Proxy. So when `getAnnotation` checks type of the annotation, the result is false.

So my questions are :

1. What can i do to have all things work without changing my method signature ?
2. Why Annotation are Proxy ?
3. Is it a configuration, compilation or library problem ?

Thanks for reading and hope you understood me.

**NB :** I knew the solution with `MultivaluedMap` or `MultipartBody`.

Informations about environnement:

```
JDK used : openjdk
Java version : 17
Gradle version : 7.3.3
Tomee version : 8.0.15 (Plus version)
Gradle dependencies : Nothing about apache cxf that can be entered in conflict with Tomee.
```